# Windows 7 to windows 10 upgrade on a VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-10

I have Windows 7 running in a virtualbox on a linux host. Now I wanted to upgrade it to windows 10 but it seems to check my hardware and reports that my VirtualBox Graphics Adapter is not compatible with Windows 10.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0.2 r102096

Comment: Windows 10 isn't fully supported by VirtualBox, your current problem, is due that incompatibility.  You can try running the 102467 build,  you also need to make sure, your system meets the requirements of Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out that it works if I download and run the [media creation tool for windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install). Without creating an installation medium it offers a direct upgrade of my windows 7 system without further hardware checks and the upgrade works as expected.